# Best way to analyse and check all database data

Tags: sql, for-loop, sql-server-2008-r2, null

One of our customers wants to make a check for each database record in each table.
The problem is, our database has currently dozens of tables (above 50) and each table already has thousands of records.

The basic check our customer wants to do is, to check for each table which columns have null values. Our customer assumes that if the platform users are only filling the basic inputs, it could mean that users are not taking full advantage of the available inputs in the platform.

What would be the best way to meet this requirement?

I already thought about doing this statistically ex:

- Table1 has 30 records with the following empty columns (Column1 , Column2, Column3)
- 30 % of the database tables have records with null values

Comment: SQL Server?  MySlq?  Oracle?  I know how I'd do it for SQL Server, but that may not apply to other databses.  I'd first query the schema tables to find columns that CAN contain null values (using a query like this: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1781/list-columns-and-attributes-for-every-table-in-a-sql-server-database/)  and then build queries on the fly for those columns, returning the count.

Comment: Thanks for replying David, is an SQL Server 2008 R2 Database. So in a way you would retrieve aggregated data right ?

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek suggestion: for each column that allows nulls, try an ALTER TABLE to disallow NULLs.  If it fails, there are nulls in that column in the table.  If it succeeds, there were no nulls in that column (and won't ever be nulls in there in the future, either).

Comment: Yes.  I'd  write an app that would first query looking for columns that can contain now, and then for each column found, create a query like Select Count(*) From [Table] WHERE [column] IS NULL, and record the table.column where the count is > 0.  That may not be the most efficient way, however, so I'm waiting for smarter people to answer.

Comment: Jou know, @JonathanLeffler, that is actually how I'd do it if I knew I wasn't supposed to have nulls and was performing a cleanup.  I'd do it on a test version of the DB first, but it would be the simplest IMO.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, That doesn't seem very efficient since i would have to revert the tables to each original design (nulls and such), but thanks.

Comment: Adding a NOT NULL constraint costs you the check; removing a NOT NULL constraint is even cheaper. However, it was a tongue-in-cheek suggestion, rather than dreadfully serious. In part, it depends on how carefully you designed the database. If you are serious and exclude nulls except when they might be necessary, then it would necessary to reset things afterwards. However, if you were casual about restricting nulls, then it gives you a good empirical indication of which columns do not actually contain nulls in practice. You can always remove the restriction later if it proves necessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i know it was a tongue-in-cheek suggestion and i appreciate it really :) i was just the first downside that came in to my mind. Each table that has columns with nulls are meant to be that way. Bottom line is, if the customer comes to the conclusion that most of the option columns are null, it means that the platform users are only filling that basic data, which could mean that users are not taking full advantage from the inputs that are available in the platform assuming the application that stores that works correctly.

Comment: I'd bet you could modify the sql in this article to do it: http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not really answering the question you posed, but I think just checking for "null" is the start of the requirement, but unlikely to be the end.

In most projects I've done with lots of data, we ended up building a validation framework, which had business logic for each table, and each field in each table.

For instance, we found that a lot of records included bogus email addresses, so we wrote a script to validate them (really simple thing initially, checking that the domain exists, and is not one of "test.com", "aaa.com", "qwerty.com" etc.). We also realized that we were getting bogus phone numbers, so we checked wether the phone numbers matched obviously made-up one (123-456789).

It's a pain in the backside, but if the business wants to understand the quality of the data, it's the only way to do it.

We ended up writing dozens of little SQL scripts which each spat out a list of "suspect" records, with the reason(s) for suspecting them. It wasn't pretty, but it was easy to extend, easy to run, an gave the business enough information to make decisions.

Comment: You actually guessed :) Today we had a metting with the client and what he ended up wanting was a Rules system to check the tables so he can make several rules for each table, like a firewall, if the records on each table fail to meet the specified requirements in the rules, we show the "invalid" records. Your idea was good too. I'll wait to see if i can get more ideas about this problem. Thanks :)